# To what extent is the HOST system still in use?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa, nextgen

The Host Computer System (HOST) used to be the backbone of the US air traffic control centers (ARTCCs). There was a lot of publicity early in 2015 about the En-Route Automation Modernization (ERAM) fully replacing it, as the FAA announced they were finally finished implementing ERAM. However, deep in the FAA website, the HOST system still seems fairly active.

I just want to clarify if it is fully out now. Is it still available as a backup? Do certain ATC systems still draw from HOST systems? Do controllers still use certain HOST systems?

Overall this is a pretty technical question, but any information is helpful.

Comment: *"deep in the FAA website, the HOST system still seems fairly active."* Where?

Comment: There are descriptions of the various air traffic control systems in the faa website, but it takes a login to view them. Basically, they imply (and also explicitly say) that the HOST system is still in service. I think they must still be decommissioning it.

Answer (score 9):

From this [news article](http://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/air-transport/2015-04-30/faa-declares-new-en-route-automation-system-operational) dated April 30, 2015:

> "As of today, Host is history," FAA Administrator Michael Huerta declared during a press conference.

From the latest [NextGen report](https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/media/NextGen_Implementation_Plan-2016.pdf) dated June 2016:

> In March 2015, the 20 planned ERAM sites achieved operational readiness, which signified the full commissioning of ERAM into the NAS and allowed the FAA to **begin decommissioning** the legacy HOST system.

So, it is fully out, it is not available as back-up, and no ATC system uses Host.

Answer (score 4):

I was lucky enough to work a career that spanned all three systems:IBM 9020, IBM 3083 (HOST) and ERAM.

HOST is no longer in use even as a backup. The backup system used to be a stand alone system called DARC (Direct Access Radar Channel). ERAM has a redundant channel of supposedly identical hardware and software as a "back up". This is problematic though. I believe the current ARTCC system uses the original DARC software hosted on the display channel (DSR) as backup.